# Cogs TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression in discord.py

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a discord bot for a personal server. I want to use cogs to separate the music player functionality from the main file.
I am raising this error when I load my `main.py` file:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.cog' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

My `main.py` file code related to cogs is this:

```
#   Cogs
async def load_extensions():
     for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            # cut off the .py from the file name
            await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load_extensions()
        await bot.start(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

asyncio.run(main())
```

In my cogs.py file:

```
import os, discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client # sets the client variable so we can use it in cogs
        self.intents = discord.Intents.default()
        self.intents.message_content = True
    
    @commands.command()
    async def command(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Yes?")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Test(client, ))
```

I initially had an error about intents, which was solved by adding `self.intents`, but I haven't been able to solve this issue. I have utilized StackOverflow, but haven't found anything specific to my issue.

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Have you checked if anything is `None` by `print()`ing out suspected objects? Also, you have `client.add_cog(Test(client, ))`, but there's nothing after the comma. That's probably the line that's causing the error; fill it up. I don't know much about Cogs or Replit, but check if `os.getenv('TOKEN')` is `None` or if the `TOKEN` is empty in the `.env` file.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder The `client.add_cog` line is not causing the issue. I removed the comma and the error is still there. My token is there and functioning as intended. 
What do you mean by "checked if anything is `None` by `print()`? 
I've tried to comment out the command and I get the same error :/

Comment: Which line is causing the error? What does the compiler say? Please post the full traceback and error. [edit] your question to comment the line which causes the error.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I believe I solved the issue. The `def setup` wasn't async/await. I did that, and the cog works. 
The error was `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
  bot.add_cog(Test(bot))`. I didn't notice it before! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `def setup(client)` must utilize async/await as it is a coroutine function.

The corrected code is:

```
    async def setup(client):
        await client.add(Test(bot)
```